# Update CarValue column in destination based on source carValue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a destination table that needs to be updated with the values that match from my source. I would like my destination to have the same CarValue as my source table would have. I have came up with the query above to pull the records that do not match my source and I want to use this to update my destination table values. Please provide examples of how to accomplish this.

```
  select
      s.*
      ,t.*
  from SourceTable as s
  full outer join DestinationTable as t
    on s.CarNo = t.CarNo and s.CarName = t.CarName
   where s.CarValue <> t.Carvalue
```

Comment: *"Please provide examples of how to accomplish this."* Please at least show us what you've tried and why it didn't work as you expect. If you're looking for example of `UPDATE` statements, there are plenty in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). What's wrong with those examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can update by using the current join statement

```
update t
    set t.CarValue = s.Carvalue
   from DestinationTable as t       
   full outer join SourceTable as s
     on s.CarNo = t.CarNo and s.CarName = t.CarName
  where s.Carvalue<>coalesce(t.Carvalue,'xYz');
```

`coalesce()` is added for the probability of existence of `null` values within the `DestinationTable`, assuming a car value never would be `xYz`.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3d88c46fb60438755d0da111afd890b2)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `full join`.  So:

```
update t
    set carvalue = s.carvalue
    from DestinationTable t join
         SourceTable s
         on s.CarNo = t.CarNo and s.CarName = t.CarName
     where s.CarValue <> t.Carvalue;
```

This does not update non-matching rows.  My guess is that you want to leave those alone.  If you do want to update them, use a `left join` and remove the `where` clause.